# Solutions available to "An introduction to Quantum Computing"?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, resource-request

I wanted to work through an introductionary text on quantum computing and came across "An introduction to Quantum Computing" by Kaye, Laflamme and Mosca. The text seems fine but there are no solutions to the exercises available (at least I didn't find them). I found a few solutions related to problems from the book but nothing complete. Are you aware of a complete set of solutions that is freely available?

Feel free to suggest other material to me if you think it better suited. My current goal is to develop some understanding of the basics.

Thank you all

Comment: Regarding the close votes: I believe this to be a legitimate question, but I doubt anyone will rush to publish solutions manuals on the internet, because it is difficult to craft nontrivial assignment problems that have attainable solutions.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I can see your point. I am not enrolled in a university and my degree is already a few years back so essentially I am on my own. I checked a few online courses on Coursera and Udemy but they seemed to be somewhat superficial with regards to mathmatics (I may be mistaken). I found tons of exercises online but without anywhere to start this seems somewhat daunting. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say start with any introductory textbook, then the problems won't seem as daunting. There are definitely homemade solution sets floating around the internet (eg to Griffiths QM boook) but I think it's best to find a book at a good level for you than to choose a book based on availability of solutions (ideally you'll be ready to write the solutions yourself!)